# Identify a surface mount zener diode with a four digits code?

Tags: diodes, surface-mount, zener, identification

I'm reverse engineering a circuit which provides a digital signal over a single pin. It is made up of only three components, all of them surface mount.

One component I assume is a zener diode. (The PCB labeled it ZD52)

The component itself has the designation of H2F9.

I couldn't find this code in any code book or key.

How can I find the specs on this diode?

(Circuit Below)
[image: Circuit]
BYC1 - 3 Pin IC. (Unknown Function)
H2F9 - Zener Diode (Assumed)
1300 - 130 Ohm Resistor (Unknown Power Rating)

This circuit connects to the very end (nothing comes after these components in the circuit) of the negative (standard current notation) terminal.

The circuits function is to output a digital signal over the pin I have labeled "Data Output".

I'm not sure exactly sure how the circuit works, as I don't know how the IC works, but I plan on using the same IC, so I just need to match the other components.

Here is a picture of the circuit...
[image: Circuit on Board]

Here is a close up of the IC...
[image]

I believe the IC's function is to output a digital signal from read-only memory, over a single line.

Comment: Assuming the H2F9 writing is hard to decipher:I guess it depends on what kind of reverse engineering you want.  If it is a zener diode the primary specification you'll be interested in is the zener voltage.  This will probably be enough to understand how it works and is easily tested.  If you want to build a circuit that behaves the same way then you'll need to take in to account how much power it needs to dissipate and how accurate the zener voltage needs to be in order to replace it.  This

Comment: ... will provide more info? What sort of info do you think we might need? Photo? Schematic? No, no need for those, I'll just use my all-seeing-eye.

Comment: You would do better to identify the byc1 part.  Once you know what it is, you can find a data sheet.  There will either be an example circuit in that, or you can tell from the maximum ratings what voltage tge zener is (the zener is there to reduce the supplied voltage to whatever the byc1 expects.). I haven't had much luck finding it, though.  Any idea what it does?  Post a picture of it, please.

Comment: @JRE There you go. Added pictures of the circuit. The IC is for outputting a signal from what I assume is read-only EEPROM.

Answer (score 1):

The SOD-123 with marking 'H2' is a MMSZ5242 zener diode from VISHAY :
[MMSZ5242 datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/1236246/0/0/1/mmsz5225-mmsz5267.html)

No picture found but the marking is described in : [diode group marking vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88912/diodesgroupbodymarking.pdf)
[image]

The SOT-23 with marking 'BYCI' is an EPROM from Texas Instruments :
[BQ2022ADBZR datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2022a.pdf?ts=1697903424549&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ2022A)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

H2 designates a 12 volt nominal V(z). F9 is a date code of F being 2018 and 2 is the month of February.

Comment: Dan H - Welcome & thanks for helping. Can you please [edit] your answer and link to the reference material which explains that decoding of the information? Does it apply to a specific manufacturer - if so, which one? Thanks. (As you're new here, FYI the main site rules, and details of how Stack Exchange differs from typical forums, can be seen in the [tour] & [help].)